# Combine functionality and Pipeline operator in F#

Tags: f#, pipeline

I'm working on a project and I want to create a really compact method for creating Entities and Attributes.

I want to do this with the pipeline operator. But I want to add extra functionality to this operator.

Like for example :

```
let entity = (entity "name")
                 |>> (attribute "attr" String)
                 |>> (attribute "two"  String)
```

In this example |>> would be a pipeline operator together with the functionality to add an attribute to the entity.

I know that this works:

```
let entity = (entity "name")
             |> addAttr (attribute "attr" String)
```

So what I want to know is, if it's possible to replace

```
|> addAttr
```

with

```
|>>
```

Thanks for the help

(I don't know if this is even possible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply define it like this:

```
let (|>>) e a = e |> addAttr a
```

Answer (score 4):

For readability, I would strongly discourage adding custom operators when a simple function will do. You could change the way `addAttr` is written to make it easier to use in a pipeline:

```
let addAttr name attrType entity = () // return an updated entity

let e =
    entity "name"
    |> addAttr "attr" String
    |> addAttr "two"  String
```

Comment: You have a point, I'm still looking into different possibilities. And one of them will be with custom operators and another will be something in the direction as you stated.